# Is there a possibility to connect from MS Access to SQL Server using alternative user Windows authentication?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, authentication

I'm trying to create a linked table connection in MS Access to a SQL Server instance table through Linked Table Manager in the External Data ribbon.

To grant access to this SQL Server instance in READONLY mode, a DBA in the organization I work for create a new Domain User Account different from my personal one.

In other applications, Windows authentication as different user in case of Excel and Powerbi and Run as different for SSMS works fine.

In MS Access there is no -Use Alternative Windows credential- term of authentication and all the others that I have tried do not function (Active Directory Password/Integrated/Interactive/servicePrincipal).

Does anyone know a possible solution to access the SQL Server from MS Access using a different Windows Domain user?

Comment: Are you trying to link the table using a common SQL Server service account created by the DBA - or is it a Windows Domain User?

Comment: it is a Windows Domain User, different from personal one I use. I tried Run As different user on MS Access but this other account does not have license for Acces.

Comment: That makes no sense - how are they going to run your application if they can't get into Access. You can install a runtime version for any user - it sounds like no one needs teh full version for what you're doing - or trying to do

Comment: i will try to explain better.
Starting point: on my PC I authenticate using my personal Windows account. Now i have two options:
1. Run MS Access using my current user, in doing so when i try to connect to sql server using integrated windows authentication i have not the permission.
2. Run MS Access using different user (the one they give me that has the permission to connect the SQL server) but the application shows the following message in the upper bar "Access(Unlicensed Product)" and the application block.

Both 1 and 2 lead to nothing, is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

open the command prompt in administrative mode and run the below command

replace <<domain\username>> with user details.
update the msaccess.exe location("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE") if it differs in your system.

C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /netonly /user:<<domain\username>> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE"

by this way ms-access will be opened using alternate user credential,
then click the "Linked Table Manager" and connect to SQL server, it will connect to SQL server using alternate user credential.

Comment: I think OP wants to run Access, not SSMS.  So from the Windows Run box, or a command prompt, or a shortcut I think the command should be C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /netonly /user:<<domain\username>> "<<path to msaccess.exe>>"

Comment: Op is asking about authenticating from MS-ACCESS - not command line

Comment: Exactly, i want to Run Access not SSMS and of course i have tried to do it as a different user but this different Window User has no valid license to run Access.